# Support x86 ABI when using sourceSets with libraries for other ABIs only

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I'm using sourceSets to disable automatic ndk-build call to integrate native libraries but I only have native libraries for armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a. When I try to build i get the error that "All modules with native libraries must support the same set of ABIs" because my dynamic feature only has 2 ABIs but my base module has x86 as well. How can I make the dynamic feature also support x86 without the native library for that?

I get the error only when I use Android App Bundle and make this a dynamic feature, it was fine before.

```
sourceSets {
        development {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["${project.buildDir}/nativelibs", "${project.buildDir}/developmentnativelibs"]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder ./x86 and put an empty empty.so file in there so my module now supports x86 ABI.

Comment: That is the right way of doing it. This informs the Android platform that the app must be started in x86 mode if supported by the device.